# unable to receive push notification in foreground react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to enable google firebase push notification with react-native fire-base. I'm able to receive push notification when an app is in the background but foreground notifications are not working. Also, how can I make push notification get displayed like other notifications such as Whatsapp notification which shows dropdown alert to users.

I tried using this [Push notification not showing in Android foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54454217/push-notification-not-showing-in-android-foreground) but still unable to set up notifications in foreground.

MainFest.xml

```
    package="com.pragyaam.grid.mobile">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

App.js code for notifications

````
  this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
    let notificationMessage = notification._android._notification._data.action;
    let recordId = notification._android._notification._data.recordID;

    const channelId = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
    'Default',
    'Default',
    firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.High
);
firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channelId);

let notification_to_be_displayed = new firebase.notifications.Notification({
    data: notification._android._notification._data,
    sound: 'default',
    show_in_foreground: true,
    title: notification.title,
    body: notification.body,
});

if (Platform.OS == 'android') {
    notification_to_be_displayed.android
        .setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High)
        .android.setChannelId('Default')
        .android.setVibrate(1000);
}
console.log('FOREGROUND NOTIFICATION LISTENER: \n', notification_to_be_displayed);

firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification_to_be_displayed);

     const { title, body } = notification;
     this.showAlert(title, body,);
 });

 const notificationOpen =await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
 if (notificationOpen) {
     const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
     this.showAlert(title, body);
 }

 this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
    const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
    this.showAlert(title, body);
});


   this.messageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage((message) => {
   //process data message
 });

 this.handleConnectivityChange = isConnected => {
   this.setState({ isConnected });
 }
}```
````

Comment: Did you find any solution for this I am not able to receive notification foreground for very first time because android channel is getting created in background only ?